# Java Glitch? Subtracting numbers?

Tags: java, double, subtraction

Is this a glitch in Java?

I go to solve this expression: 3.1 - 7.1

I get the answer: -3.9999999999999996

What is going on here?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is what's going on.

Comment: See things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798830/double-precision-values) and a ton of others. (Hey, where's the WECSSKAFPN article go?)

Comment: This has got to be the most common programming question. ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A great explanation can be found here. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/

> Floating point arithmetic is rarely exact. While some numbers, such
>   as 0.5, can be exactly represented as a binary (base 2) decimal (since
>   0.5 equals 2-1), other numbers, such as 0.1, cannot be. As a result, floating point operations may result in rounding errors, yielding a
>   result that is close to -- but not equal to -- the result you might
>   expect. For example, the simple calculation below results in
>   2.600000000000001, rather than 2.6:
>
> ```
> double s=0;
>
> for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
>     s += 0.1;
> System.out.println(s);
> ```
>
> Similarly, multiplying .1*26 yields a result different from that of
>   adding .1 to itself 26 times. Rounding errors become even more serious
>   when casting from floating point to integer, because casting to an
>   integral type discards the non-integral portion, even for calculations
>   that "look like" they should have integral values. For example, the
>   following statements:
>
> ```
>   double d = 29.0 * 0.01;
>   System.out.println(d);
>   System.out.println((int) (d * 100));
> ```
>
> will produce as output:
>
> ```
>  0.29
>   28
> ```
>
> which is probably not what you might expect at first.

See the provided reference for more information.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by several others you cannot count on `double` if you would like to get an exact decimal value, e.g. when implementing monetary applications. What you should do instead is to take a closer look at [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("3.1");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("7.1");
BigDecimal result = a.subtract(b);
System.out.println(result);      // Prints -4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Computers are 100% so in the math world that is correct, to the average person it is not. Java cant have a error on a specific number as it is just code that runs the same way but has a different input!

P.S. Google how to round a number

Comment: `Java can't have an error`??  I've never met a computer system that didn't have a bug ....

Comment: No I mean in a simple addition, its like saying 5+5 will be correct 6+5 wont,

Comment: Well that was a processor, but still i guess you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

rounding errors in floating points

same way that `3 * 0.1 != 0.3` (when it's not folded by the compiler at least)

Answer (score 1):

Automatic type promotion is happening and that is the result.

Here is some resource to learn.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html

The next step would be is to learn to use formatters to format it to the given precision / requirements.